# Promise Js: Wait till promise fulfilled

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm working with [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) for promises in Node.Js, and was wondering how can I make a function return when the promise is fulfilled(completed).The behavior I want is :

```
function getItem(){
  functionReturningPromise.then(function(result){
    //do some operation on result
    return result;
  });
}
```

However, the above implementation won't return anything since the promise isn't completed at the time of execution. What would be the best workaround around this?

The purpose of getItem is to modify whatever functionReturningPromise returns, and then return it

Comment: You can't.  If your operation is async, then the result of that operation cannot be returned synchronously, ever.  Simply return your promise and have the caller use `.then()` on the promise to get the result.  That's how async development works in node.js.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't, `var value = someAsyncFunction()` is not possible (until we have generators, at least). Promises are viral, once you use a Promise in a function, its caller must use `then` and the caller of the caller too, etc up to your main program. So, in the function that calls `getItem` you have to change this

```
item = getItem();
do something with item
```

into this

```
getItem().then(function(item) {
    do something with item
})
```

and `getItem` should return a Promise as well

```
function getItem(){
  return functionReturningPromise().then(function(result){
    //do some operation on result
    return result;
  });
}
```

(Theoretically it can also be a callback, but I prefer to always return promises).

Comment: +1 but... you don't really need `Promise.resolve(result)`. Just return `result` since you're inside a `then`. and please don't suggest callbacks when using promises.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım: right, it's late here ;)

Comment: Returning the promise does what I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

> The purpose of getItem is to modify whatever functionReturningPromise returns, and then return it

Then, I think you could simply do

```
functionReturningPromise.then(getItem);
```

where

```
function getItem(valueFromPromiseResolution){
    //do some operation on valueFromPromiseResolution
    return whatever;
}
```

Comment: Here you're just passing a function in as the callback, you can't return that value outside of the promise.

Comment: @richardpringle You are right. Still, not going to delete the answer even if it's wrong, let the downvotes come; I deserve them.

Comment: this was actually helpful cause that's what I was doing lol.